# Тире после придаточного перед главным? Тире после местоимения перед сказуемым?

Tags: пунктуация

> ...Но, обнаружив в моём лице зрителя, паренёк тотчас оживился и
>   придумал новую шалость. Он проверил, как работает пробка на его
>   фляжке. При сильном сдавливании бутылки она пропускала очень тонкую,
>   но быструю струю холодной воды. И пока стайка ребят под управлением
>   двух педагогов была увлечена процессом организации в пары – он,
>   опустив глаза, понурясь, как и положено провинившемуся, начал
>   потихоньку брызгаться. Я – расхохоталась. За мной отреагировал и
>   ресторан и... Проказник получил больше внимания, чем ему было
>   необходимо, и чуть ли не за ухо (а быть может, мне так показалось,
>   потому что дотянуться до него крошечный страж точно никак не мог) был
>   увлечён в толпу, которая сорвалась с места, уступая пространство новой
>   группе туристов.

Оба тире авторские. Все остальные знаки, включая скобки, мои.

Оправданно ли дробятся предложения? "Проказника" я то поднимаю, то опускаю, и отточие перед ним моё (после "ресторана" была просто запятая)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если хотите оставить оба тире, то сделайте их похожими, требующими интонации противопоставления для личных местоимений (хотя функция этих тире, если подходить строго, разная):

***И, пока стайка ребят под управлением двух педагогов была увлечена процессом организации в пары, он - опустив глаза, понурясь, как и положено провинившемуся, -  начал потихоньку брызгаться. Я – расхохоталась.***

Не кажется ли вам, что перед второй И нужна запятая, так как после неё предполагается действие другого лица:

***За мной отреагировал и ресторан, и***... *Проказник получил больше внимания...* Хотя это не принципиально, потому что вторая И может соединять, например, однородные сказуемые.

Comment: Я забыла, как здесь ставится тире. Напомните кто-нибудь, пожалуйста!)

Comment: Тире — Alt (держим) 0151 (справа).

Comment: Спасибо!!! Век живи — век учись!)

Answer (score 1):

Я бы оставила **только второе тире.**

*И пока стайка ребят под управлением двух педагогов была увлечена процессом организации в пары, он, опустив глаза, понурясь, как и положено провинившемуся, начал потихоньку брызгаться. Я – расхохоталась.*

Нет причин (по Розенталю) для постановки тире в СПП, как нет причин и для обособления деепричастной конструкции.

Второе тире авторское.

Здесь пауза обозначает **неожиданность реакции**, а также **увеличивает значимость и объем** этой короткой фразы.

Связи между личными местоимениями не вижу.

Answer (score 1):

Я не вижу оснований для *второго* тире (пусть первое будет авторским). Оно уместно было бы в контексте "*разделения труда*", а не реакции "её" на поведение другого, например:

> Мы занялись каждый своим делом. Он - начал брызгаться из бутылочки. Я - уткнулась в
>   телефон и принялась читать накопившиеся сообщения.

"Пропускала" (струю) лучше заменить на "испускала (выпускала)", поскольку говорится не о *протечке* пробки, а намеренно организованной шалости (из бутылки сделан импровизированный водяной пистолет).

Comment: 1) В СПП к авторским тире  на месте запятой относятся более строго, чем к постановке тире при отсутствии знаков. 2) Неожиданность действия  обозначается тире во всех случаях, здесь нет ограничений. 3)Струю пропускала пробка, так как была неплотно закрыта.

Comment: Здесь нет эффекта неожиданности: он долго примерялся к своим действиям. Первое тире раздражает меня не так сильно.

Comment: 1) Речь не о нем. Эта пауза для читателя, который ожидает реакции рассказчика.  2) Розенталь указывает случаи, когда допускается тире в СПП. И меня как раз удивляет первое тире, поставленное не по этим правилам (раздражает, как Вы говорите).

Comment: Пожалуй, и первое лишнее, но оно не обращает на себя внимания, в то время как второе (между подлежащим и сказуемым) создаёт ложный след, заставляя искать, что же сделал соизмеримое с этим "расхохотанием" первый персонаж. Этим оно и злит.

Comment: Нет, это совершенно случайное несовпадение :).

Comment: Ладно, наш автор разберется, не правда ли? А мы, как читатели, ему немного помогли.